# PHP socket server send response after some minutes

Tags: php, client, response, serversocket

I have a socket server that is working greatly, but I'm trying to implement something new and it's not working.

In my socket server I send message to client using a $response string. If this string is different from empty value the server sends the message for client.

The $response is defined by the message server got from client first, for example:

```
if($data=="CODE:A")
{
    $response="Hello";
}
```

So, what i need to do is send a message to client after 3 minutes, but is not only this because of sleep(180) it works, my problem is that i need to define send 2 different answers to client if the code in $data is equal to CODE:C, the first message must be sent without wait and the second after 3 minutes, for example:

```
if($data=="CODE:C")
{
     $response = "Msg 1";
}
else if($data=="CODE:C")
{
     sleep(180);
     $responde = "Msg 2";
}
```

My problem is that if I set the code like this above, the $response is sending message to client only after 3 minutes and is only sending first message, the second is not sent.

And if I put the code of the second if inside the fisrt creating only 1 if, after 3 minutes the $response to client is always Msg 2.

How can I implement this to works?
I already try use $t = time()+180 and check if time is equal $t but nothing happens.

Comment: `if ($data=="CODE:C") {} else if ($data=="CODE:C") {}`, I'm probably blind or something but those conditions look identical.

Comment: How are you sending the message? Here you're just setting a variable value

Comment: Maybe you don't understand, but i want to call this two if to the same condition, as i said in the question, if i set this if($data=="CODE:C){ $response="Msg 1"; sleep(180); $response = "Msg 2"} the response is sent after 180 seconds but only sends Msg 2 and i need to send Msg 1 and after 3 minutes Msg 2

Comment: @apokryfos the message is sent by a fwrite($client, $response);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write each message to the socket, ideally the receiving end will know to poll the server for more data correctly and not terminate the socket session:

```
if($data=="CODE:C")
{
    fwrite($client, "Msg 1"); //Write the first message to the socket
    fflush($client);
    sleep(180);               //Wait
    fwrite($client, "Msg 2"); //Write the second message to the socket
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but this works in part. Now I can send the 2 Msg but is only sent after 180 seconds all messages

Comment: @AndréPiropo you may need to flush the handle buffer (check update).

Comment: still not working, it's sending the two messages after 3 minutes not one and after 3 minutes other

Comment: It works... I didn't do as you told and because of it not works, I was setting fwrite ($client, $response); and I think this was blocking and just sending after 180 seconds, but when i did like you told, works gratly! thanks